# Cypress - iframe handling

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-iframe

I have some code that tries to catch elements inside an iframe but I just keep getting thrown back an error

```
it('Send Medication',function(){
       cy.get('.aut-iframe') 
       .should(iframe => expect(iframe.contents().find('body')).to.exist)
       .then(iframe => cy.wrap(iframe.contents().find('body')))
       .within({}, $iframe => {
            cy.get('.pending-medication-check-box').click({force:true})
```

This is the error that I get:

[image]

[image]

Lastly, this is the iframe info:

[image]

Comment: `<iframe id="Your App: '...'" class="aut-iframe" src="..."></iframe>` is part of the Cypress test runner, so you cannot use Cypress test commands to access it - why do you want to? If you have another iframe that is actually part of the app, you need to change the selector in the test.

Comment: you are exactly right, Fody, after doing some more digging I noticed that the actual iframe I needed was embedded deep within the one I was originally trying to use

Answer (score 5):

I would assume you are just missing retries for fetching the iframe until the body is loaded. Simple `get` and `should` combo doesn't wait for this to happen. Official docs state you should use `.its('body')` when working with iframes, so try something like this:

```
cy.get('.aut-iframe').its('body').then((body) => { cy.wrap(body).should('...') }
```

Reference: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/#header

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin.
2. After installation write `import 'cypress-iframe';` under `cypress/support/commands.js`
3. Then finally your code should look like:

```js
cy.frameLoaded('.aut-iframe')
cy.iframe('.aut-iframe')
  .find('.pending-medication-check-box')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

Comment: thanks for the info Alapan, but i am getting the following error.
`Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: .aut-iframe, but never found it`

Comment: can you post the entire html code for the iframe and the element you are trying to click?

Comment: `<iframe id="Your App: 'CypressAutomationTest'" class="aut-iframe" src="https://demo.******.com/****"></iframe>`

`<input type="checkbox" class="pending-medication-check-box">
<span class="checkbox"></span>
::after`

Comment: I can see the checkbox outside the iframe. Can you directly try `cy.get(‘.pending-medication-check-box’).click()` and see if it works.

Comment: thanks for teh help Alapan you code example was of really good assistance

Comment: Did it solve the issue for you?

Comment: Hi @AlapnDas, could you kindly help me understand do we need to use *.should('be.visible')* every time we are accessing element within an iframe? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

First in your command file add this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', () => {
return cy
    .get('.aut-iframe')
    .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')      
    .then(cy.wrap)
})
```

Then in your test you can use the command above in this way:

```
cy.getIframe()
  .get('.pending-medication-check-box').click({force:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is pulling content from a different origin `chromeWebSecurity: false` in your `cypress.conf.json` file otherwise it will fail to find the `contentDocument` of the iframe.

PS this may not necessarily be your issue, but I've seen a lot of people with this problem so sharing the solution is always worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts here's what worked for me. Managed to pinpoint the credit card number field which is 1 out of 3, hence the index in the code.
Hope, it helps someone else as well.
NOTE: 3 input fields have the same locator piece but a different index.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("populateCardInformationForm", (creditCardDetails) => {
  cy.log("Going to populateCardInformationForm()");
  // Populate Name on card
  cy.get('#name-on-card')
  .scrollIntoView()
  .should('be.visible')
  .type(creditCardDetails.nameOnCard);
  // Populate Credit Card number
  const getIframeBody1 = () => {
    return cy
      .get('iframe[name*="privateStripeFrame"]')
      .eq(0)
      .its("0.contentDocument.body")
      .should("not.be.empty")
      .then(cy.wrap);
  };
  getIframeBody1().find('input[class^="InputElement"]').type(creditCardDetails.cardNumber);
});
```